# Redeclaration of variable, in a switch statement in C

Tags: c, variables, switch-statement, local-variables

I'm using a switch statement that basically looks like this:

```
switch (command):
case '+':
   int key;
   scanf("%i", &key); 
   //do stuff
   break;
case '-':
   int key;
   scanf("%i", &key);
   //do stuff
   break;
....
```

It appears I'm not allowed to redeclare `int key` along the case ladder, even though they break as separate blocks of operation. I get compile error `redeclaration of 'key'  with no linkage` so I'm just using `key` without typecasting it again. The program seems to run fine.

Is this acceptable? Is it safe?

Comment: Your code seems quite repetitve to me. Is it because you simplified for posting here or you actually have repeating code pieces which is a bad practice at the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not legal, and consequently it's not safe. But it's easy to fix. Just use blocks in your switch statement to limit the scope of your declarations:

```
switch (command):
case '+': {
   int key;
   scanf("%i", &key); 
   //do stuff
   break;
}
case '-': {
   int key;
   scanf("%i", &key);
   //do stuff
   break;
}
```

Comment: Why not just declare `int key;` at the beginning of the function definition?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: That would work in this case, but in general different branches of the `switch` require different local variables. It's a question of style, really. I prefer to put local variables in the smallest possible scope. (And so does Google: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Local_Variables#Local_Variables )